# Validation of UPDATE query in SQL using Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, forms, validation, security, web

I have a details view that has one field that allows an update.  You can select open or close.  When clicking "edit" it allows the user to update the field using the query:
set status = @Status
where (Job = @Job) and (Job_Operation = @Job_Operation)
UPDATE Job_Operation
set last_updated  = current_timestamp
where (Job = @Job) and (Job_Operation = @Job_Operation)

This works fine, but would like to proceed the list box "open/close" with a validation textbox that would require the user to enter a PIN number to confirm their identity.  If the PIN number matched a list, the update would succeed, and if not, the update would return an error.

Comment: You've not show us the code you're using now to allow the user to edit, you've provided no details about the language or platform (Visual Studio is neither - it's an IDE), and without that information we can't possibly offer a solution, so I'm presuming you're just asking for permission to make this change. You have mine - go ahead. (And as an aside, wouldn't it be better to prompt the user for a PIN that authorizes the edit *before* allowing them to start editing and not after?)

Comment: It's written in ASP.   The update command is written in SQL.   Currently any user can click and update link,  select the item from the list, and click update.

Comment: That information (with much more detail) needs to be in your question, not buried in a comment. Spend a few minutes reading [ask], and then come back here and [edit] your question.